# How to use gcloud and python in one ci/cd pipeline

Tags: python, gitlab-ci, gcloud, google-artifact-registry

I'm new in Google Cloud Artifact Registry and I managed to publish a module to there. However, now I want to automate this by putting it in a git pipeline but unfortunately I can't get this to work.

I Think the problem is that I have to use 2 diffrent images (python and google/cloud-sdk) but you can't use this in one script. I have tried 2 diffrent solutions but both didn't work.

I know it's not efficient code, but I'd like to get it working first

Version1:

```
stages:
    - test
    - install
    - authenticate
    - deploy
python-installs:
    image: python:latest
    stage: install
    script:
        - pip install build twine
        - pip install build
        - python -m pip install keyring
        - python -m pip install keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth

login-to-gcp:
    image: google/cloud-sdk
    stage: authenticate
    tags:
    - script
    script:
        - echo $GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON > deployment_service_account.json
        - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file deployment_service_account.json
        - rm deployment_service_account.json
unit-test-job:
    image: python:latest
    variables:
        PIP_CACHE_DIR: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.cache/pip"
    cache:
        paths:
            - .cache/pip
            - venv/

    before_script:
        - python3 -V  # Print out python version for debugging
        - pip3 install virtualenv
        - virtualenv venv
        - source venv/bin/activate
        - pip3 install requests
        - pip3 install python-dotenv

    script:
        - python3 -m unittest discover

deploy-package:
    stage: deploy
    image: python:latest
    tags:
        - script
    only:
        - master
    script:
        - pip install build
        - pip install build twine
        - python -m pip install keyring
        - python -m pip install keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth
        - python -m build
        - python -m twine upload --repository-url https://xxxxxxxx-python.pkg.dev/devote-staging/xxxxxxxx/ dist/*
```

Error: /bin/bash: line 127: gcloud: command not found, but if I remove the line with gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file deployment_service_account.json I got error that i'm not authenticated.

Version 2:

```
stages:
    - test
    - build
    - authenticate
    - deploy
.python-installs: &installs
    image: python:latest
    before_script:
        - pip install build twine
        - pip install build
        - python -m pip install keyring
        - python -m pip install keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth
.login-to-gcp: &logintogcp
    image: google/cloud-sdk
    tags:
    - script
    before_script:
        - echo $GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON > deployment_service_account.json
        - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file deployment_service_account.json
        - rm deployment_service_account.json
unit-test-job:
    image: python:latest
    variables:
        PIP_CACHE_DIR: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.cache/pip"
    cache:
        paths:
            - .cache/pip
            - venv/

    before_script:
        - python3 -V  # Print out python version for debugging
        - pip3 install virtualenv
        - virtualenv venv
        - source venv/bin/activate
        - pip3 install requests
        - pip3 install python-dotenv

    script:
        - python3 -m unittest discover

deploy-package:
    stage: deploy
    <<: *installs
    <<: *logintogcp

    image: python:latest
    tags:
        - script
    only:
        - master
    script:
        - python -m build
        - python -m twine upload --repository-url https://xxxxxxxx-python.pkg.dev/devote-staging/xxxxxxxx/ dist/*
```

Error:
/bin/bash: line 119: gcloud: command not found

Comment: The error says gcloud sdk is not installed on the machine used. May be try using the image that has both installed ?

Comment: I shared my solution, can you have a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @destiny,  `Error: gcloud: command not found` means cloud-sdk is not installed on your machine.

Try using `google/cloud-sdk:latest` tag which includes cloud cli latest image.

Before that make sure you have installed the `Google Cloud CLI Docker image`.

To install Cloud cli image from [docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/google/cloud-sdk/) follow below steps:

1. To use this image, pull from Docker Hub, run the following command:

```
 docker pull google/cloud-sdk:latest
```

2. Verify the install

```
docker run -ti  google/cloud-sdk:latest gcloud version
               Google Cloud SDK 159.0.0
```

3. or use a particular version number:

```
docker run -ti google/cloud-sdk:160.0.0 gcloud version
```

Or if you want to install Cloud cli image from hosted on Google Container Registry.
Refer this [document](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-docker#installing_a_specified_docker_image).